# Find the limit using integral sums

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Find the limit expressing it as the limit of integral sums of a proper chosen function.

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+n)}$$.

I know that the idea to choose the specific points $\xi_{k} \in [x_{k-1}, x_{k}]$ is to choose the start or end point of the subinterval $(\xi_{k} = x_{k-1}$ or $\xi_{k} = x_{k})$, or the subintervals middle point $(\xi_{k} = \frac{x_{k-1}+x_{k}}{2})$.

Still I do not any clue how should I approach the problem and how should I finish it. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I hope the problem is understandable after translating it from Swedish to English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{(n+1)\ldots(n+n)}$$
Then
$$ \ln a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(n+k)-\ln n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\int_{0}^1\ln(1+x)dx=2\ln 2-1 $$
Thus $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n=e^{2\ln 2-1}=\frac{4}{e}$.

Comment: +1, beautiful answer. Don't we need to prove that the limit exists though?

Comment: The limit exists by the Riemann sums theorem, thus $(\ln a_n)$ converges and, since $\exp$ is continuous, $(a_n)$ converges aswell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean that since you've proved that the limit is equal to the definition of an integral it must exists?

Comment: The Riemann sums theorem states that for $f$ Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, $$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(a+k\frac{b-a}{n}\right) $$ exists and is equal to $\int_a^b f$. This can be taken as the definition of $\int_a^b f$ or deduced from other definitions.